# How to use code to get all properties of a single azure user?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var delta = await graphClient.Users
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName,jobTitle,mobilePhone")
    .GetAsync();
```

I noticed this, is there an easier way to do? Like `Select("all property")`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one to get All :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var users = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

Also Just to add more flavor, You also write your queries like this :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("mail eq 'pashyant@26543.onmicrosoft.com'")
    .Select( e => new {
             e.DisplayName,
             e.Mail 
             })
    .GetAsync();
```

Here you can pass filter criteria if you want to apply. In select clause you can mention the columns which you wanted in output **but if you not providing anything in select will give you all**.

Microsoft Link for more details : [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can create own helper method that will use reflection to get all properties of type you need and create a select statement from these properties.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IUserDeltaRequest SelectAll(this IUserDeltaRequest request)
    {
        var value = string.Join(",", typeof(User).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)).Select(x => x.Name));
        return request.Select(value);
    }
}
```

I select only properties of type string.

```
var delta = await graphClient.Users
.Delta()
.Request()
.SelectAll()
.GetAsync();
```